# Error while zipping specific files in unix

Tags: bash

I am trying to zip all the png file in a directory using the below command, but getting error.

```
sudo zip pngimages.zip media/*.png
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/zip: Argument list too long
```

This directory contains more then 3000 images.

I did some research and trying to zip the images group by group—instead of zipping all files in a single go, I thought of dividing it to groups—but am new to bash script/command so am struggling with it.

Comment: SuperUser has a duplicate: [zip: Argument list too long (80.000 files in overall)](https://superuser.com/questions/272696/zip-argument-list-too-long-80-000-files-in-overall)

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

As seen in `man zip`

```
find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@
```

which means you'd do

```
find media/ -name "*.png" -print | zip pngimages.zip -@
```